# Angular algolia instant search

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am pretty new to instant search and algolia and I was wondering how to achieve two things with this tools.

1: Is it possible to bind to `<ng-ais-search-box placeholder='Search for products'>
</ng-ais-search-box>` ?? I would like to fill the search box with some string when I click somewhere but I can't find the way to bind the input of the search form.

2: How to achieve filtering. It's not clear to me how to filter my data. I have set in the dashboard facets for some fields and I am able to filter using a list of facets based on `.title` property but I don't want to give user ability to pick the filters. I want to programmatically set the filter values and display them to the user based on different views.

If anyone is able to help I would appreciate !!! I cant find the solutions and I am in big need of this :( 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For customising the behaviour of the search box, you can create a [custom widget](https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/guides/customize-widgets.html#customize-widgets) based on the original version of ng-ais-search-box.

For the second question, we're currently busy making a "configure" widget to deal with those kind of use cases, but for now you can also make a custom widget, and set the invisible filter using the helper, which is provided to custom widgets.